# HardDisk Quota — Cedar Stack (Heroku)

Tags: heroku, cedar

I know that the maximum slug size allowed is 200 MB. But what is the maximum disk space you can use per instance? Say I'm downloading a couple of files when the node process is running.

Comment: The maximum slug size has been increased to 200MB: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/72 and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug-size.

Answer (score 17):

```
heroku run bash
~ $ df -h /tmp
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
-                     620G  6.1G  583G   2% /tmp
```

You have approximately 620Gb in the /tmp folder.
Any other folder doesn't really matter, as they're readonly anyway.

Comment: Will I be able to use the entire 620GB given that it's a shared stack?

Comment: Yes. The tmp folder is yours only.

Comment: That is not true (anymore?). The available disk space of the `/tmp` folder is shared with your "neighbours". It is isolated in terms of file permissions and vsibility, but you need to handle "no space available" yourself.

Answer (score 3):

When I ran `df` on one of my instances just now (Cedar 14), I get 304G total, 240G available. Still a lot, but less than the responder above. Just an FYI to check your specific instance.

`~ $ df -h /tmp
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/evg0-evol0  304G   49G  240G  17% /tmp`

Answer (score 0):

I think the total size for whole server is 620GB. you can run df -k . in free account and I got 394267100 byte.. 400mb

> You have approximately 620Gb in the /tmp folder. Any other folder
>   doesn't really matter, as they're readonly anyway.