# How much disk space do heroku plans have?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I creating an app that works like an DMS(Document Management System) so my client will be uploading PDF's, XLS's and DOC's.

Comment: According to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099378/harddisk-quota-cedar-stack-heroku), it looks like 620GB.

Answer (score 24):

You don't want to be uploading anything to Heroku, it has an ephemeral file system which is reset on restarts/deploys. Anything uploaded should be uploaded to a permanent file store like Amazon S3

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: So can you store a Worpress site on heroku and store all the images on S3?

Answer (score 16):

From [How much disk space on the Dyno can I use?](https://help.heroku.com/DGUDV63H/how-much-disk-space-on-the-dyno-can-i-use) of the heroku help site:

> **Issue**
>
> You need to store temporary files on the Dyno
>
> **Resolution**
>
> Application processes have full access to the available, unused space on the mounted `/app` disc, allowing your application to write gigabytes of temporary data files. To find approximately how much space is available for your current Dyno type, run the CLI command `heroku run "df -h" --size=standard-1x -a APP_NAME`, and check the value for the volume mounted at `/app`.
>
> *Different Dyno types might have different size discs, so it's important that you check with the correct Dyno size*
>
> **Please note:**
>
> Due to the Dynos ephemeral filesystem, any files written to the disc will be permanently destroyed when the Dyno is restarted or cycled. To ensure your files persist between restarts, we recommend using a third party file storage service.

The important part here is that it is not the same value for every plans and is possibly subject to changes with time:

> *Different Dyno types might have different size discs, so it's important that you check with the correct Dyno size*

Answer (score 11):

The correct answer is that it would appear you have 620 GB.

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16938926/3973137

[image]

Answer (score 8):

https://policy.heroku.com/aup#quota

```
Network Bandwidth: 2TB/month - Soft
Shared DB processing: Max 200msec per second CPU time - Soft
Dyno RAM usage: Determined by Dyno type - Hard
Slug Size: 500MB - Hard
Request Length: 30 seconds - Hard
```

Maybe you should think about storing data on amazon s3?

Comment: What underlies this request length limit of 30s on Heroku? Is a a typical hosting restriction? I have a Node app that is assuming potentially longer durations (most of the duration is network data transfer).

Comment: @ChrisPrince Heroku says, "The decision to timeout requests quickly wasn't made to avoid having long-running requests on our router, nor to only have fast apps on our platform, but because standard web servers do not handle these types of requests particularly well." (https://blog.heroku.com/timeout-quickly)

Downloads from an app only have to transfer something every 55 seconds to stay alive, and uploads are recommended to be done directly to a third-party storage service. (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#long-polling-and-streaming-responses)